# Authentication flow for oauth2 login and register in springboot with jwt

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am writing a authentication feature in jwt springboot with oauth2. I have already written the normal authentication (using username + password for authentication) ,  but it fail will combining oauth2.

Here is the oauth2 i want to achieve:

1.Registration :

- oauth2 login + create record + update record
- when oauth2 success create an inactivated account in database and navigate to the register 2 page in frontend to proceed the registration(adding other preference), then update the user as activated

2.login

- normal login
- using oauth2 login,find if the database have the user record and navigate to homepage in frontend, if no record , login fail

**Problem Faced:**

my oauth2 authentication have two different situations (one with create record in db one with find the record). Meanwhile, it seems that there is only like url "/login/authorization/google' can process the oauth2.Then i will redirect to the google page automatically in springboot.Hence, i am wondering where can i seperate the login flow and register flow in oauth2 in spring security.

Here is the code:

```
  @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Return chain that allows any request and has no authentication
        return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthFilter(), OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.class)
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/login/oauth2/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/user").permitAll();
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })

                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults())


                )


                .userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).httpBasic(withDefaults())


                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo.userAuthoritiesMapper(this.userAuthoritiesMapper())

                ).successHandler(new CustomOAuth2SuccessHandler())
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/api/auth/loginSuccess")).exceptionHandling(e -> e.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))).build();

//

    }
```

Possible Approach:

what i have try is in the above code , i have try to get the url before redirect in oauth2 by the provider like google in the customAuthfilter above, for example like '/login/authorization/google?requestType=login' to distinguish login and register and use the customsuccesshandler to get back the data after oauth2 login success and map it to responsible endpoint for further action.

I have tried to save the record in header , but it will fail since the request will be redirect to the external website for oauth2.  I have thinking of using cache to store if it is register or login request, but it seems that it may required the use of session and sessionid as key which i may want to use jwt for my application.And it seems there is less resource talking about the flow like this.Any suggestion for my case.I dont like if there is any wrong concept for it